# Displaying dynamic data from AJAX request to Controller in table view ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to pass data returned from Controller with an AJAX call to my table inside a view where it is asked for (with filters). To be more precise, there are 3 filters: Date and time, employee and visitor. Depending on which combination you pick, Controller returns filtered data from database.

When a view is loaded, it shows all visitors in database that have a value in field `Departure`. I want it to show filtered visitors after filters are applied.

Archive.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Visitor_Management.Models.Visitor>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Archive";
}

<div>
    <h2>"Archive"</h2>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<form class="form-inline" id="formFilters" runat="server">
    <div>
        <label style="margin-left:10px;">Date and time:</label>
        <input type="text" name="picker" id="picker" class="form-control" size="30" />
        <label style="margin-left:10px;">Employee:</label>
        <input type="text" id="employee" class="form-control" placeholder="select an employee" />
        <label style="margin-left:10px;">Visitor:</label>
        <input type="text" id="visitor" placeholder="select a visitor" class="form-control" style="margin-right:20px;" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn navbar-btn btn-primary " name="filter" id="filter" value="filter">Filter</button>
    </div>

    <div>&nbsp;</div>
</form>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped text-center" id="archiveTable">

    <tr>

        <th class="text-center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
        </th>

        <th class="text-center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>

        <th class="text-center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Arrival)
        </th>

        <th class="text-center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Departure)
        </th>

        <th class="text-center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employee)
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
            ID Card
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
            Pass ID
        </th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
     var Date = item.Datum.ToShortDateString();
     <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Arrival)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Departure)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CardID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PassID)
        </td>

     </tr>

     }

</table>
```

AJAX call

```
<script>
    $('#filter').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Filter",
            data: {
                'datepicker': $('#picker').val().toString(),
                'employee': $('#employee').val().toString(),
                'visitor' : $('#visitor').val().toString()
            },
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST", 
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Works");
                $('#archiveTable').html(result)
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error")
            }
        }); 
    });  
</script>
```

VisitorsController.cs

```
public ActionResult Filter(string datepicker,string employee,string visitor)
        {
         List<Visitor> filterList = new List<Visitor>();

            //filter data to get an filtered list

            return View("Archive",filterList);
        }
```

It says it "Works" from alert in success part of AJAX, but I don't get any new (filtered) data in table, like nothing happened and the view is just reloaded (refreshed).

If I return `JSON` type, with `ActionResult` being `JsonResult`, I can read the data, and filtered data is true and correct but I am still unable to load that data in my table.

Comment: You are returning the whole page and trying to set it as HTML of the table? Try to put the table in partial view, and return it from your controller action.

Comment: @adolja Can you write an example? I tried with partial view, but couldn't get it to work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to take out your table in partial View (let's call it _ResultTable and put your table inside div with resultTable id in your view):

```
@model IEnumerable<Visitor_Management.Models.Visitor>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Archive";
}

<div>
    <h2>"Archive"</h2>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<form class="form-inline" id="formFilters" runat="server">
    <div>
        <label style="margin-left:10px;">Date and time:</label>
        <input type="text" name="picker" id="picker" class="form-control" size="30" />
        <label style="margin-left:10px;">Employee:</label>
        <input type="text" id="employee" class="form-control" placeholder="select an employee" />
        <label style="margin-left:10px;">Visitor:</label>
        <input type="text" id="visitor" placeholder="select a visitor" class="form-control" style="margin-right:20px;" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn navbar-btn btn-primary " name="filter" id="filter" value="filter">Filter</button>
    </div>

    <div>&nbsp;</div>
</form>
<div id="resultTable">
     @Html.Partial("_ResultTable", Model)
</div>
```

Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Visitor_Management.Models.Visitor>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped text-center" id="archiveTable">

        <tr>

            <th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
            </th>

            <th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
            </th>

            <th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Arrival)
            </th>

            <th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Departure)
            </th>

            <th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employee)
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                ID Card
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Pass ID
            </th>

        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
         var Date = item.Datum.ToShortDateString();
         <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Arrival)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Departure)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CardID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PassID)
            </td>

         </tr>

         }

    </table>
```

and then return it from your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Filter(string datepicker,string employee,string visitor)
{
    List<Visitor> filterList = new List<Visitor>();

     //filter data to get an filtered list

     return PartialView("_ResultTable",filterList);
 }
```

In your ajax post just set the html of your div to action result. And you need to add preventDefault to submit button so it doesn't submit your form twice.

```
<script>
    $('#filter').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "Filter",
            data: {
                'datepicker': $('#picker').val().toString(),
                'employee': $('#employee').val().toString(),
                'visitor' : $('#visitor').val().toString()
            },
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST", 
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Works");
                $('#resultTable').html(result)
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error")
            }
        }); 
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution right now and I think I am missing something. If I remove my table from Archive view, and generate partial view named "_ResultTable", shouldn't I refer to that inside <div id="resultTable> with "@Html.Partial("_ResultTable")" where I removed a table from Archive?

Comment: Yes,  you should